# How to fix "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" even if the Path variable is specified (crossplatform)

Tags: java, groovy, path

I am trying to run a Maven build from within a Groovy script. It seems to not be able to find Maven though.

I already checked the path variable and it contains the correct path. If I specifically execute mvn via `C:/…/mvn.cmd` it works.

I now use `System.getenv()` which fixed the missing Java_home variable, but this doesn't help with mvn. Weirdly enough commands like `git …` work without even specifying the environment.

I also know that I could fix this by just opening a cmd and running the commands there but I cannot do this as it also has to run on a mac or linux machine.

```
File workingDir = new File(*MYWORKINGDIRECTORY*)
def mvnbuild = 'mvn package'.execute(System.getenv().collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }, workingdir)

mvnbuild.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

This produces the following error message:

```
2019-11-05 13:57:12.631 ERROR *MYSCRIPT* FAILED.
Reason:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "C:\Users\*MYWORKINGDIRECTORY*"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I run some different command through this, e.g. `where` it works just fine:

```
def mvnbuild = 'where mvn'.execute(System.getenv().collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }, workingdir)

mvnbuild.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

produces

```
C:\*THECORRECTMAVENPATH*\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn
C:\*THECORRECTMAVENPATH*\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\mvn.cmd
```

Allthough it produces the same error as above if I try to run `npm`

PS: I also checked `System.getenv()`, it contains the correct Maven path.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you define the M2_HOME environmental variable and added %M2_HOME%\bin to your path variable (supposing you are under Windows). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, M2_HOME is defined and the absolute already was in the path variable, I just added the relative path too but that didn't change the result :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error on Windows is because you are not giving it the full name, including the extension. You don't have to give it the full path as long as the containing directory is in the `Path` variable.

You can type `mvn` in the Windows command interpreter (cmd.exe), and it will work because is somewhat clever about extensions. But Groovy and Java doesn't go through that.

Instead, Groovy's `.execute()` method delegates to Java's `ProcessBuilder`, which on Windows calls a native function called `CreateProcess` in the win32 API. In this function, if you do not specify an extension, it will assume it is a `.exe` file. This is why the `where` command work (which is actually `where.exe`) and `git` (which is actually `git.exe`) but not other executable types like `.bat` and `.cmd`, such as `mvn.cmd`.

To fix it in a way that is compatible with multiple platforms, the best option I see is to check which platform is used and alter the command accordingly. Something along these lines:

```
def mvnFileName = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows') ? 'mvn.cmd' : 'mvn'
def mvnbuild = "$mvnFileName package".execute() // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that tomorrow. I somehow wanted to avoid different cases for different environments ... But I think I'll have to go with that